# Image stitching not working with more than 3 images

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

I am trying to stitch images for constructing panorama. But I am unable to stitch more than 3 images at a time. The code on which I am working on it is in
[here](https://github.com/MrGrayCode/OpenCV/blob/master/Panorama/stitch.cpp)
When I run stitching more than 3 images, the error I am getting is:

> Camera parameters adjusting failed

```
Ptr<BundleAdjusterBase> adjuster;
adjuster = makePtr<BundleAdjusterReproj>();
adjuster->setConfThresh(conf_thresh);
if (!(*adjuster)(features, pairwise_matches, cameras))
{
    cout <<"Camera parameters adjusting failed." << endl; return -1;
}
```

Can someone help me in refining this code or solving the problem. The sample images I am working to stitch are

Comment: Has nothing to do with the objective content particular question, but: when do people learn, how to [state a proper](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) question? This includes a meaningful topic, proper text in the question itself as well as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't link to an external source!

Comment: I scanned your code, but its too long. The stitcher does work on more than 3 images so there must be more information about where your particular example crashes etc.

Comment: Its working on some images only. I have some images when I am trying to stitch them,its showing above error. I am unable to upload images on which i worked because of less reputation can I mail u @GPPK